# How to wordwrap a long string in ion-item

Tags: ionic-framework, word-wrap

IONIC has two problems about word-wrap in ion-item:

1. String would be truncated by the dots appended at the end, how to show full content without dots ?
2. Automatic line breaks and responsive are not working in Firefox (Chrome is ok), how to fix this problem in Firefox ?

```
<div class="row responsive-sm">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="item item-body">
            <ion-item class="wrap" style="word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-all;">
            #fashion #fashion #fashion #fashion #fashion #fashion #fashion #fashion #fashion #fashion #fashion #fashion #fashion #fashion #fashion #fashion #fashion #fashion 
            </ion-item>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is Full HTML to show the problem
[codepen](http://codepen.io/din2/pen/EVxEQY)

Answer (score 132, accepted):

**For ionic 1:**

Add `item-text-wrap` **class** to item.

```
<ion-item class="item-text-wrap">
  some long string
</ion-item>
```

**For ionic 2:**

Add `text-wrap` **attribute** to item.

```
<ion-item text-wrap>
  some long string
</ion-item>
```

Comment: I use class="wrap item-text-wrap" style="word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-all;", and it works now, thanks.

Comment: it works in ionic 4 also. Thanks. But it reduce the text size. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 105):

In Ionic 2, use the `text-wrap` attribute

```
<ion-item text-wrap>
  text here wraps to multiple lines
</ion-item>
```

Comment: hi , the ion-item without text-wrap only displays one line with ellipsis.. how to configure it to allow 2 line and then ellipsis... when inspecting `ion-item` the setting are in `ion-label` which includes `text-overflow` , `overflow` and `white-space`  can you help, thanx

Comment: this is the correct one. tried it on ionic 3 and fixed it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me.  I had to change the `<ion-label>` to `white-space: normal;`

Comment: it works in ionic 4 also. Thanks. But it reduce the text size. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 42):

For Ionic 4, use `text-wrap` on your `ion-label` element, like so:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label text-wrap>
         Multiline text that should wrap when it is too long
         to fit on one line in the item.
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
```

**UPDATE: 10/30/2019** - CSS utility attributes are now deprecated in the latest version of Ionic 4, and will be going away completely in Ionic 5.

It is recommended to use `class="ion-text-wrap"` moving forward:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">
         Multiline text that should wrap when it is too long
         to fit on one line in the item.
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the best way to browse the various Ionic secret CSS classes such as "ion-text-wrap".  If you look on the doc page for the ion-label component, the only mention of ion-text-wrap is in a buried piece of sample code.  Is there more comprehensive documentation somewhere that describes such things?

Comment: @deltamind106 yes they are called Ionic CSS Utility Classes and can be found here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities

Answer (score 24):

If you want a custom CSS class to have the same word wrapping effect, just add

```
white-space: normal;
```

to your class.

Source: [ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-text-wrap/8580)

Answer (score 14):

**Ionic 4**

**class="ion-text-wrap"**

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">Long Text</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
```

[Link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities#text-alignment)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with CSS without adding ionic's volatile-garbage to your HTML like so

[image]

I think that means style any ion-label inside an ion-item with the following style...