# How to display big texts inside ionic radio button?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I have an application in which I need to have some ionic radio, the problem is that when the text is too long , it does not appear completely!

**Screenshot:**
[image]

I try to put the follow attributes:

```
style="overflow: initial; white-space: initial;"
```

but it doesn't work :/

So my question is, what changes i need to do in order to display the full text inside the ion radio?

Comment: @Quantastical didn't work :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fast solution:** Just add  class="item-text-wrap"

**Another solution**: The correct answer that solved my problem was add the follow css:

```
 .wrapping-list .item-content, .wrapping-list .item {
    overflow: initial;
    white-space: initial;
}
```

and give the class="wrapping-list" to every ion-radio!

Answer (score 1):

As [Aaron explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38644186/2551933) in a similar question, just use `<ion-item text-wrap>` in Ionic 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try CSS-word-wprap

optionaly you could add an &shy after each caracter so the browser breaks it.

```
p.test {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Comment: didn't work in this case! text continues to show with '...'