# ionic paragraph is single line in ion-item button

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I got the followintg html:

```
<button ion-item (click)="doSome()" style="margin-left: 72px; display: block; padding-left: 0" >
    <div padding-left style="display: block">
        <h6>Function</h6>
        <p>{{user.function}} </p>

        <h6 padding-top>About</h6>
        <p>{{user.about}}</p>

        <h6 padding-top>Task</h6>
        <p>{{user.task}}</p>
    </div>
</button>
```

And this is the result:
[image]

I found a `ion-item` directive is causing this. How can I fix this?

**EDIT1: more information**

The result i'm looking for is this:
[image]

It is accordion view. Basically it is a list and each item has the accordion-component. In the accordion I have the above html. Because I want the item in the accordion the be clickable with ripple effect it must be `<button ion-item></button>`

Accordion:

```
export class AccordionComponent {

  @Input('expanded') expanded = false;

  constructor() {

  }

  toggle(){
    this.expanded = !this.expanded;
  }
}
```

Simple accordion html:

```
<div *ngIf="expanded" @ngIfAnimation>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

**EDIT2:**
Any solution with an expandable listitem will be fine. Both the listitem and the expandedlistitem require the ripple effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wordwrap a long string in ion-item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335101/how-to-wordwrap-a-long-string-in-ion-item)

Comment: Are you need to use <div> ? ion item can serve good look and lots of good feature, and its also provide text-wrap which solve your problem

Comment: @denmch I found that too. Unfortunately it doesn't fix my problem. Probably because I am using the button.

Comment: @Utpaul I don't think I need the div. Though, I need the button so I can;t use the ion-item component.

Comment: @RobinDijkhof if you update your wanted view i will solve this ...... ??

Comment: @Utpaul check my edit

Comment: @RobinDijkhof About text are multiple line or single line

Comment: @Utpaul The about and the task should be multi-line

Comment: @RobinDijkhof well just don't wrap everything in that one button. Put the other entries below the button in own button entries. Also would be nice if you provide a sample jsfiddle.

Comment: I can not understand your question clearly. In short, you want an `ion-item` can [collapse](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp)?

Comment: @Duannx. Yes, and I want both the item and the collpase to have the ripple effect on click.

Answer (score 0):

Use ionic card instead. You can attach a click event to a card also

```
<ion-card (click)="functionName()">
  <h6>Function</h6>
    <p>{{user.function}} </p>

    <h6 padding-top>About</h6>
    <p>{{user.about}}</p>

    <h6 padding-top>Task</h6>
    <p>{{user.task}}</p>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: But I dont need a card. It is a button in a self made accordion.

Comment: I can't use <oin-item>  because I need the ripple effect. Therefor it must be `<button ion-item></button>`

Answer (score 0):

this should do multiline paragraphs.

```
<button ion-item (click)="doSome()" style="margin-left: 72px; display: block; padding-left: 0" >
<div padding-left style="display: block">
    <h6>Function</h6>
    <p text-wrap>{{user.function}} </p>

    <h6 padding-top>About</h6>
    <p text-wrap>{{user.about}}</p>

    <h6 padding-top>Task</h6>
    <p text-wrap>{{user.task}}</p>
</div>
```

when not try text-wrap in the button tag also